# Why is the background of a swing window changing on Mac and not on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, macos, swing, awt

I have a fullscreen JFrame that I developed on my MacBook, and it worked great. The background was able to change colors and stuff. Now I moved it over to my Windows box and the background is white, and it doesn't seem to want to change when I tell it to. Why could that be?

This is the code for setting up my windows (in a nutshell):

```
JFrame frame;
DisplayMode dm;
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setBackground(new Color(0.3F, 0.3F, 0.3F));
dm = new DisplayMode(Main.width, Main.height, 32, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
screen = new ScreenManager();
screen.setFullScreen(dm, frame);
```

This is the code for setting JFrames fullscreen.

```
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Window;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ScreenManager
{
    public static GraphicsDevice vc;

    public ScreenManager()
    {
        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        vc = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    }

    public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm, JFrame window)
    {
        window.setUndecorated(true);
        window.setResizable(false);
        vc.setFullScreenWindow(window);
        if (dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported())
        {
            try
            {
                vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                //No need to do anything.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that this may have something to do with the code you've written.

Comment: Please include an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) and we can help a little more.

Comment: Not exactly the shortest code snippet, but you should be able to see what's going on from there. Basically on Mac, you get the nice gray color that I've specified, and on Windows you get a very ugly white. And later on in my code I have the color set differently, but that doesn't change on the Windows machine either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I could think of is the JFrame is being set to a color--this won't do anything.

Try this

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0.3F, 0.3F, 0.3F));
```

You'd be setting the color of the pane itself instead of just the Frame.